# Changing 72 ppi to 300 ppi for printing without losing quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have been given a set of images in .jpg at 72 ppi and need to convert them to .pdf for printing. The final outputs should be in .pdf. How should I go about it? Will changing the ppi to 300 and exporting them as .pdf in Photoshop suffice or is there any other way? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Hi Hana. Welcome to GDSE.  There are a couple of problems with your question.  Jpegs don't normally need to be converted to PDFs for printing. Also, it's very difficult to answer questions about print resolution which don't give details of the size of the image in pixels, and the size the image will be printed at. Can you edit your question and add these details. Thanks.

Comment: Thing is that is what the client wants. The images are all of different sizes under A3 and I believe the final result will be printed in A4. They need a single pdf file.

Comment: This is how I am doing(quite possibly wrong): Open the photo in photoshop. Change 72ppi to 300 ppi without changing the width and height and save the jpeg as pdf in high quality print. Is this the right way?

Comment: If the image is to be printed at size A4 at 300 dpi, then it must be 2480 x 3508px (or bigger).  That's how you know if the resolution is good enough for printing. So, are the images you have good enough for printing?  I have no idea, and I can't answer the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: All are different sizes, one is for eg. 31x47cm and another is 54x40cm, both at 72ppi. I tried printing a few pages and they are okay quality. Not super sharp.

Comment: The dimensions in pixels are shown in the Image Size dialog.  What are they?  I already told you what they need to be for a good quality print. You already have the information to work it out. You can't make raster images any sharper by enlarging them - it won't work.

Comment: There are around 80 images. Most of them are below the dimensions you said. One is at 2246x1498px. It won't work then like you said

Comment: So, that image would be too low quality for a great print at A4. It might be OK, but only just.  Resampling will make the image blurrier. It won't improve anything.  You can't get more quality from an already low resolution image. It's not possible.

Comment: So then there is also no point in changing 72ppi to 300 since it should be printed as well is there?

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only point of enlarging those low resolution images might be to reduce any obvious pixelization, however the images will not get any sharper, if anything they will look slightly blurrier.

Resampling basically adds no new detail to the images, it merely enlarges them, and if the quality is not there to begin with, enlarging will simply make them look blurrier, as the software will try to reinterpolate the extra pixels you are adding.

You might be able to add some sharpening in Photoshop, but no guarantees it will help. Photoshop's sharpening doesn't really "sharpen", it only helps accentuate the contrast of edges in a photograph.

Ultimately the images are not really good enough for good quality printing.  Speak to your client, and ask if they have access to the original high resolution images.  If not, then perhaps suggest they print them smaller so the quality problem is not so obvious.

Comment: Oh no smart sharpen actually un-blurs or in effect sharpens. Technology developped thanks to hubbles manufacturing error, its amazing what you get when worlds best mathematicians have a problem. But this has a downside it does increase noise . However only works well if you use the right deconvolution shape.

Comment: @joojaa Hubble's error was an unintended linear transformation. Elementary math tells that it can be fixed with applying the inverse. This case was lucky and the inverse transform existed. Quite a big matrix to identify and invert, I think. The theoretical basement has existed 150 years. Practical numerical calculation with modern computers is much younger altough iterative methods as principles and tuned for manual work were known  The case was totally different than the questioner's problem (=too sparse sampling).

Comment: I have to agree with @user287001. The problem with Smart Sharpening is that blur due to resampling is totally different in structure from real lens blur that you get with a camera lens being out of focus.  It works well enough on real lens blur, but it's practically useless for blur caused by resampling. See quick example I made [here](https://i.imgur.com/oRgPReB.png).  I didn't even include the version made with the "lens blur" setting, which I tried on the resampled image, because it was so bad.  Even the "gaussian" setting is pretty awful compared to the real lens blur example.

Comment: @joojaa (continued) Too sparse sampling also is a linear transform, but it hasn't the inverse.

Comment: @user287001 I wasnt implying you can fix images by unblurring i just pointed out photoshop can unblurr. Anyway its not really my fault that Adobe does not want to allow me to insert the convolution kernell but rather only allows me to choose from 2 existing ones. Anyway while its true that the smart sharpen wont work well for general enlarging, it works well for some types of images like comics. especially if you do the scaling and unblurring in stages and dont jump too fast to several times bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Already an old case, but I met this problem in practice just today. The discussion: "I have got these images, put them into the print instead of your placeholders...what, useless! Why? Is this a joke? In our webpage they look out wonderful!!!!"

Too low pixel resolution can be increased by resizing the image with resampling in Photoshop. It unfortunately doesn't know what's missing and blurry areas grow wider in pixels, but no original sharp edge will step in, it stays away.

The problem has been around so long that clever enlargening software which try to guess sharp edges and thin lines has been developed. I know two good enlargers, but surely there are others. The two I have tried and seen working are Smilla (freeware) and OnOne Resize (commercial).

The next image pair has in the left a photo snippet which is enlargened to 400% with Photoshop's ordinary resize (bicubic sharp). The right half has got the same enlargement in OnOne resize.

[image]

As you see, it really can guess the edges, even some of the moustaches are guessed right(=still thin). But it cannot recreate the missing detail - someone can in high zoom see it as a drawing.

Comment: The only problem is, the image no longer really looks like a photograph, but more like some kind of painting. Of course, it's still way better than Photoshop's Smart Sharpening on a similar image, but still less than the ideal situation which would be an original high resolution image.  It might help at a push, if the resampling/resizing isn't too extreme. 400% might be pushing it a bit too far.